# Write all of the processes to a text file

Tags: c#

I am trying to write all of the processes to a text file, but it will only write the first process in my system. Would you guys mind seeing if there is anything wrong or that I can adjust to fix this issue?

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        
    {
        try
        {
            var ap = Process.GetProcesses();
            SaveFileDialog sfdv2 = new SaveFileDialog();
            if(sfdv2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach(Process process in ap)
                {
                    string path = sfdv2.FileName;
                    BinaryWriter bw2 = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(path));
                    bw2.Write("test" + " "  + ap.ToString());
                    bw2.Dispose();
                }
                
                
            }
           
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
```

Comment: Why use binarywriter and why create a new file inside the loop?

Comment: You need to open the file before the loop, write to the file inside the loop and close the file after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Take a step back and see what you are writing.

For each process in the list, you create a file with the same name (and overwrite the previous one) and write "test {process}" in it.

The code does what you tell it, and that's why you end up with only one process in the file.

You can fix this by opening the file outside the loop and closing it afterwards, or even better, you can write it with a `using` statement. Also, please don't use `BinaryWriter` for writing to text file. There are many other methods, and the suggested one is `StreamWriter`. Take a look at this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file) to see some examples.

```cs
string path = sfdv2.FileName;
// with using, the file will be also closed when it's disposed.
using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path))
{
  foreach(Process process in ap)
  {
      file.WriteLine("test " + ap.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about this, I am quite new to c# so i do not exactly know all of these functions. However thank you very much for teaching me something new!

Comment: @MickyD thank you for the suggestion, I have edited my answer!

Comment: This: `file.WriteLine("test " + ap.ToString());` is not correct. You don't want to write `ap.ToString()` there (nor `process.ToString()` actually, but it's up to the OP to figure out what the content of each line is going to be)

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider using the Async version of the button click event handler. This is because writing to files is potentially a long running process. So you might want to start it and not wait to block your UI. Combine this with StreamWriter.WriteAsync methods and use in conjunction with await.
e.g.

```
   private async void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     try
       {
           var ap = Process.GetProcesses();
           SaveFileDialog sfdv2 = new SaveFileDialog();
           if(sfdv2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           { 
               string path = sfdv2.FileName;
               using(StreamWriter bw2 = new StreamWriter(File.Create(path)))
               {
                  foreach(Process process in ap)
                  {
                      await bw2.WriteAsync("test" + " "  + process.ProcessName.ToString());
                  }
               }
           }           
       }
       catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the initial problem into smaller, easier tasks:

Lines we want to write down:

```
var linesToWrite = Process
  .GetProcesses()
  .Select(process => $"test {process.ProcessName}");
```

UI:

```
using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog() {
    //TODO: here we put dialog's parameters
  }) {

  if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    //TODO: here we put the main routine 
  }
}
```

Combining it all together:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog() {
      //TODO: here we put dialog's parameters
    }) {

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
      File.WriteAllLines(dialog.FileName, Process
       .GetProcesses()
       .Select(process => $"test {process.ProcessName}")); 
    }
  }
}
```